# Distinguish peak in image with high resolution

Tags: image-processing, imagej

[image] [image]I am working on finding minor shift in multiple image of a wire throughout its length, and then plot the shift.

I have downloaded imagej open source software. I must say its lucky to find such amazing software being freely available with lot of functionalities. Thanks to Imagej fraternity.

We capture image of wire and one place, and move to next place few mm away, capture another one and so on. This wire has twist along the length but very minute to distinguish. Now I have such 1000 images and I would like to plot trend of twist along the length by looking at images in sequences.

To simplify the process, we have thought of using grey scale comparison of image at that particular point of each image.

My question is: How to automate such lengthy process. How to ensure that each image consider a particular threshold for boundary detection of a particular shape. I am not from image processing field, so kindaly ignore my novice explanation and feel free to ask more. Please guide. Many thanks.

Comment: please provide a few images, maybe with some annotations.
what peak are you talking about? what shift?

Comment: Please also indicate your OS, and programming environment. You can update all the information requested by clicking the `edit` button under your post http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41044315/edit

Comment: Thanks. I have added image link. Wire has two layers. Inner layer move along the length w.r.t. outer layer. I would capture images at 1,2...n places along the length and measure the shift i.e. at location1, may be X1=X2, at next location it may be X1<X2 and so on. Basically sinusoidal movement...

Comment: you should also provide an image in full resolution so people can process them as you would.

Comment: It is not clear to me where you are measuring from/to. Are you measuring from the top of the image to the top of the central wire? And from the bottom of the central wire to the bottom of the image, or to the top/bottom of the blueish coloured thing?

Comment: It has limit to add image of greater than 2 MB. My image is ~4 MB. Now I convert to GIF and post. Does it help.

Comment: My thought is to compare intensity profile of all captured images and then plot the variation of central part w.r.t. its next close layer. we do not want manual measurement as the shift is expected to be very minute (<1um) and operator can make err in selecting the correct point. So, everytime we capture an image, an intensity data is exported and all such data compare the shift....

Comment: Windows 2007, I can somewhat understand macro writing (as being instructed).

Comment: I have added high a image with proper annotations yesterday. Did it help...Kindly revert.

Comment: Did my image of yesterday helped. Its in my post as link. I see confusing links because 2 of my image link are side by side mentioned in the post. Please refer the latest one with proper annotations.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? If not, you might want to ask on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/) to get more image processing-specific help.